# Fill two-dimensional list with values instead of initializing it first with zeros

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array that I want to fill up with values that represent powers but my problem lies in the speed of the code because the two-dimensional array is 100x100 size and I don't want to first initialize it with 100x100 list of zereos then fill up the list with values but rather fill up the 100x100 two-dimensional list by values directly. My code is shown down below

```
x_list = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, (max_x - min_x)+1)
 y_list = np.linspace(min_y, max_y, (max_y - min_y)+1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_list, y_list)
Y = Y[::-1]
Z = [[0 for x in range(len(x_list))] for x in range(len(y_list))]         #Z is the two-dimensional list containing powers of reach position in the structure to be plotted

for each_axes in range(len(Z)):
    for each_point in range(len(Z[each_axes])):
        Z[len(Z)-1-each_axes][each_point] = power_at_each_point(each_point, each_axes)
#The method power_at_each_point is the one that calculates the values in the two-dimensional array Z
```

An example what I want to do is instead of doing what is shown below:

```
Z_old = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
for each_axes in range(len(Z_old)):
    for each_point in range(len(Z_old[each_axes])):
        Z_old[len(Z_old)-1-each_axes][each_point] = power_at_each_point(each_point, each_axes)
```

I want now to not initialize the Z_old array with zeroes but rather fill it up with values while iterating through it which is going to be something like the written below although it's syntax is horribly wrong but that's what I want to reach in the end.

```
 Z = np.zeros((len(x_list), len(y_list))) for Z[len(x_list) -1 - counter_1][counter_2] is equal to power_at_each_point(counter_1, counter_2] for counter_1 in range(len(x_list)) and counter_2 in range(len(y_list))]
```

plus the method of power_at_each_point is shown below with it's related methods if it helps you understand what I wanted to do:

```
 #A method to calculate the power reached from one node to the other for contourf function

def cal_pow_rec_plandwall_contour(node_index_tx, receiver):   
nodess_excel = xlrd.open_workbook(Node_file_location)
nodes_sheet = nodess_excel.sheet_by_index(0)

node_index_tx_coor = [nodes_sheet.cell_value(node_index_tx - 1, 3), nodes_sheet.cell_value(node_index_tx - 1, 4)] #just co-ordinates of a point
distance = cal_distance(node_index_tx_coor, receiver)
if distance == 0:
    power_rec = 10 * (np.log10((nodes_sheet.cell_value(node_index_tx - 1, 0) * 1e-3)))
    return power_rec  #this is the power received at each position
else:
    power_rec = 10 * (np.log10((nodes_sheet.cell_value(node_index_tx - 1, 0) * 1e-3))) - 20 * np.log10((4 * math.pi * distance * 2.4e9) / 3e8) - cal_wall_att([node_index_tx_coor, receiver])
    return power_rec


def power_at_each_point(x_cord, y_coord):  #A method to get each position in the structure and calculate the power reached at that position to draw the structure's contourf plot
fa = lambda xa: cal_pow_rec_plandwall_contour(xa, [x_cord, y_coord])
return max(fa(each_node) for each_node in range(1, len(Node_Positions_Ascending) + 1)) #Node_position_ascending is a list containing the co-ordinate positions of markers basically or nodes.
```

If someone could tell me how can I fill the two-dimensional array Z with values from the bottom of the top as I did right there without initially setting the two-dimensional array to zero first it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a list of lists for Z instead of just using a NumPy 2D array? Pre-filling the array and then replacing the values may make your code take 1.5x as long, but using a list of lists and looping in Python will make it take 10x as long, and surely that's a much bigger issue?

Comment: Meanwhile, can you give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of some not-quite-working code that's sort of similar to your real code, isn't complete, and has irrelevant stuff in it?

Comment: Can you poste the  function `power...` ?  Maybe it is possible to vectorize it ? If not, I would try to use lists instead of the array. If speed is a big issue you could use cython or f2py.

Comment: @abarnert Yes I think that is one of the problems but I am not quite familiar with python so I made it as trivial as it can be.Can you help me and post how I can change the code so that it can achieve what I did above in a faster way?

Comment: I will an example now by editing my question.

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: That's exactly why Moritz and I both asked for a _complete_ example. If we can see exactly what you're doing, we can show you how to do the same thing with a numpy array and, hopefully, numpy vector operations, and you can understand how it corresponds to what you showed us. If we see something different, the best you can get is a vague example that may not be relevant to your real code and may be hard to understand.

Comment: @abarnert I've added the whole bulk of code that I wrote that is related to my problem I hope that helps you figure out what I want to do why the code is slow like you said. If you want me to clarify anything else please say it.

Comment: are you sure that the speed bottleneck lies within the storage loops ?

Comment: @Moritz It definitely 100% does because the rest of my code takes less than 10s to run but this part takes about 25 mins to run so yea im sure.

Comment: Yeah, but you call your function many times. Probably the function has to be optimized. Did you checked how much time the loops need and how much time the function itself ?

Comment: @Moritz I will change the function first as abarnert stated and then i'll check the time the loops and the function itself takes but how can I do that in python?

Comment: google for profiling and python

Answer (score 0):

OK, first, you want to create a NumPy array, not a list of lists. This is almost always going to be significantly smaller, and a little faster to work on. And, more importantly, it opens the door to vectorizing your loops, which makes them a *lot* faster to work on. So, instead of this:

```
Z_old = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
```

… do this:

```
Z_old = np.zeros((3, 5))
```

But now let's see whether we can vectorize your loop instead of modifying the values:

```
for each_axes in range(len(Z_old)):
    for each_point in range(len(Z_old[each_axes])):
        Z_old[len(Z_old)-1-each_axes][each_point] = each_point**2 + each_axes**2
```

The initial values of `Z[…]` aren't being used at all here, so we don't need to pre-fill them with 0, just as you suspected. What *is* being used at each point is `r` and `c`. (I'm going to rename your `Z_old`, `each_axes`, and `each_point` to `Z`, `r`, and `c` for brevity.) In particular, you're trying to set each `Z[len(Z)-1-r, c]` to `r**2 + c**2`.

First, let's reverse the negatives so you're setting each `Z[r, c]` to something—in this case, to `(len(Z)-1-r)**2 + c**2`.

That "something" is just a function on `r` and `c` values. Which we can get by creating `arange`s. In particular, `arange(5)` is just an array of the numbers `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`, and `arange(5)**2` is an array of the squares `0, 1, 4, 9, 16`.

The only problem is that to get a 3x5 array out of this, we have to elementwise add two 2D arrays, a 3x1 array and a 1x5 array, vice-versa, but we've got two 1D arrays from `arange`. Well, we can `reshape` one of them:

```
Z_old = (3 - 1 - np.arange(3))**2 + (np.arange(5)**2).reshape((5, 1))
```

You can, of course, simplify this further (you obviously don't need `3 - 1`, and you can just add a new axis without `reshape`), but hopefully this shows directly how it corresponds to your original code.

Comment: The part where you reversed the negatives you said I'm trying to set each `Z[r,c]` to `(len(Z)-1-r)**2 + c**2` but in my case its that I'm setting the position `Z[len(Z)-1-r, c]` in the 2D array to `r**2 + c**2` instead.

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: But that does the exact same thing. Look at this simplified: setting `Z[3-1-0]` to `f(0)`, `Z[3-1-1]` to `f(1)`, `Z[3-1-2]` to `f(2)`, vs. setting `Z[0]` to `f(3-1-0)`, `Z[1]` to `f(3-1-1)`, and `Z[2]` to `f(3-1-2)`. In each case, `Z[0] == f(2)`, `Z[1] == f(1)`, and `Z[2] == f(0)`. (If you really don't trust this, you can always build the array upside-down and then just flip it by indexing `[::-1]`; that only wastes a tiny bit of time…)

Comment: oh,yes I do see it now. So for my original code where does the `(3-1-np.arange(3))**2` fit ? Because in my code i'm not really squaring each position but rather executing the power_at_each_point method. I want to replace your example line `Z_old = (3 - 1 - np.arange(3))**2 + (np.arange(5)**2).reshape((5, 1))` to fit mine at `Z[len(Z)-1-each_axes][each_point] = power_at_each_point(each_point, each_axes)`. What corresponds to len(Z) now and how can I get to call my method inside instead of squaring as a function?

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: You have to figure out how to vectorize the operation. Can you implement `power_at_each_point` in terms of values you already have (or can easily get) in an array? In this case, the real guts of the function are just a call to another function, `cal_pow_rec_plandwall_contour`, which apparently opens an Excel spreadsheet and pulls out a value. You need to change things to open the spreadsheet once, and ideally to pull out all of the values into an array that you can use.

Comment: @abanert I just want to the code to output something similar to that although the syntax that i'm gonna write is wrong but you can get what I want to do is fill the np.array matrix by values directly in one time. Something like this as follows:
`Z = np.zeros((len(x_list), len(y_list))) for Z[len(x_list) -1 - counter_1][counter_2] is equal to power_at_each_point(counter_1, counter_2] for counter_1 in range(len(x_list)) and counter_2 in range(len(y_list))]`

Comment: @arbarnert what you said was true!!!! I switched from extracting my information from the excel sheet directly to just extracting it all to a list of lists and then getting my information from it and it drastically changed my run time from 20 minutes to 20seconds!!!! THANK YOU DUDE!

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: Great! Converting that list of lists to a 2D array may get you down to 5 seconds, or save memory, but if you're happy with 20 seconds, better to stick with something simple that you understand. :)

Comment: i'll try the 2D array approach and i'll be sure to tell you what happened you're great man thank you once again ! :)