# Fill up a 2D array while iterating through it

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

An example what I want to do is instead of doing what is shown below:

```
Z_old = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0]]
for each_axes in range(len(Z_old)):
    for each_point in range(len(Z_old[each_axes])):
        Z_old[len(Z_old)-1-each_axes][each_point] = arbitrary_function(each_point, each_axes)
```

I want now to not initialize the Z_old array with zeroes but rather fill it up with values while iterating through it which is going to be something like the written below although it's syntax is horribly wrong but that's what I want to reach in the end.

```
 Z = np.zeros((len(x_list), len(y_list))) for Z[len(x_list) -1 - counter_1][counter_2] is equal to power_at_each_point(counter_1, counter_2] for counter_1 in range(len(x_list)) and counter_2 in range(len(y_list))]
```

Comment: You're still focusing on the wrong thing. Initializing the array with 0's takes so close to no time that it's not worth worrying about. The problem is the inner loop, where you call the very slow `arbitrary_function` X*Y times. That's where all of your time is spent, so that's the part you need to optimize.

Comment: The 1st expression is fine (use `[x,y]` indexing).  The 2nd is a misguided immitation of a list comprehension.

Comment: In the future, it would really help if, when you create a question related to another question, you include a link to it, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360970/). There's a lot of background information that's relevant to this question that nobody's going to know unless they happened to remember that question, or go through all the same comments and edits as you went through last time.

Comment: @abarnert okay i'll be sure to include that next time,sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained in my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360970/), you really need to vectorize `arbitrary_function`.

You *can* do this by just calling [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) on the function, something like this:

```
Z = np.vectorize(arbitrary_function)(np.arange(3), np.arange(5).reshape(5, 1))
```

But that will only give you a small speedup. In your case, since `arbitrary_function` is doing a huge amount of work (including opening and parsing an Excel spreadsheet), it's unlikely to make enough difference to even notice, much less to solve your performance problem.

The whole point of using NumPy for speedups is to find the slow part of the code that operates on one value at a time, and replace it with something that operates on the whole array (or at least a whole row or column) at once. You can't do that by looking at the very outside loop, you need to look at the very *inside* loop. In other words, at `arbitrary_function`.

In your case, what you probably want to do is read the Excel spreadsheet into a global array, structured in such a way that each step in your process can be written as an array-wide operation on that array. Whether that means multiplying by a slice of the array, indexing the array using your input values as indices, or something completely different, it has to be something NumPy can do for you in C, or NumPy isn't going to help you.

---

If you can't figure out how to do that, you may want to consider not using NumPy, and instead compiling your inner loop with Cython, or running your code under PyPy. You'll still almost certainly need to move the "open and parse a whole Excel spreadsheet" outside of the inner loop, but at least you won't have to figure out how to rethink your problem in terms of vectorized operations, so it may be easier for you.

Comment: Dude to need to realize that you're hitting me with too much information at once and i'm not that familiar with python that's why im facing those performance issues. I'll try to read what you said 10 more times and understand what I should do to solve my performance issues I really appreciate the help. One thing I can say is that i've already extracted the excel sheet information into a list of lists in python but I can definitely try to change that into a np array and work on that instead.

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: Sorry, but if you actually want to learn how to program efficiently with NumPy, there's a lot to learn, and you have to start with the basics. I can't write an answer that gives you a complete tutorial ranging from what vectorization means all the way up to tips and tricks for vectorizing different kinds of problems; there is no substitute for you putting in the effort to learn it.

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: And meanwhile, you also need to learn the broader topic of optimizing in general: how to profile your code to figure out which parts are slow, and how to try to guess which parts matter so you know what to profile, how to get a feel for which optimizations will affect which parts, and so on.

Comment: i'm keen to always learn and now as I am in the current time trying to apply what you said. It's only the fact that I've been working with python not too much to know that many stuff and ofcourse there's much to learn. I'll start with working with the extracted data from the excel sheet as np array and working with it.

Comment: I had no idea arbitrary_function was doing file processing ... this isnt going to help you at all ...

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: The good news is, once you get the hang of it, learning how to vectorize your loops is often kind of fun. Until, of course, you run into something where you come at it from every angle and none of them work, at least not without creating a massive X*X*Y*Y-sized array that uses up all your RAM and slows things down even worse, which happens pretty much at least once in every NumPy project. But that's what the internet is for; someone else has always done the same thing and been smarter than me (at least in my experience). :)

Comment: to be fair vectorizing python functions is largely a convienience  that provides no speed-up over looping. (in fact im pretty sure numpy library implements it with simple looping constructs)  (that said its still a good idea I was the +1)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: That's my point: turning the loop into a `vectorize`d call will provide a small, constant speedup (just like turning the loop a listcomp), but not nearly enough to make a difference; you really need to turn the innermost part of the logic into a sequence of steps NumPy knows how to vectorize natively (or at least into a C function call rather than a Python function call).

Comment: @abarnert so if I use an array or a list of lists to extract my data to be used by the arbitrary function that will speed up my code instead of getting my information from the excel sheet?

Comment: @MahmoudAyman: I don't understand what you're asking. The key is to look at the innermost call in your code that takes time. You're calling `power_at_each_point` on each element. That has its own loop inside it. And inside that loop, you're calling `cal_pow_rec_plandwall_contour`. My suspicion is that the body of that function takes up 1000x more time than the function calls and loops around it, so whatever you do to optimize out those function calls and loops isn't going to help. But profiling is better than suspecting, so try running it under `cProfile` (but note the caveats in the docs).

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = 10
cols = 10
Z = numpy.array([ arbitrary_function(each_point, each_axes) for each_axes in range(cols) for each_point in range(rows) ]).reshape((rows,cols))
```

maybe?

Comment: but I want to use Numpy arrays isn't that possible?

Comment: This isn't going to help much; you're just turning a nested `for` statement into a nested comprehension. You can do a little better by turning it into a NumPy nested loop using `np.vectorize`. But, as I explained in my answer, I'm pretty sure we're talking about maybe a 15% speedup (your version) or a 20% speedup (mine) on the part of the code that takes under 0.1% of the total time, so it's irrelevant.